# WHY NOT use awk inside perl?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

Probably this question has been asked many times about being able to include the awk one liner inside your perl script. But these questions were too specific to the problem wherein:

1. a different approach was provided as a suggestion OR
2. the syntax within the existing code was rectified OR
3. Majority of the times -> solutions were provided using perl because experts favored using either awk or perl because they both do the same job. Yes. Perhaps. But i think awk is designed for targetting specific problems which can be solved in awk better than perl.

**Example:** I have the output of `ls -lart` and the 9th column is filename. I can easily do that in awk as `ls -lart|awk '{print $9}'`. Same thing of course can be done using perl using `readdir()`. But extracting 8th column or 7th column is not that easy in perl? Things become worse if I have to extract data pipe it to awk pipe it to sed etc.

**Another Example:**
I have a specific DIR which has many files in some format like:

```
ABC_9090_DEF_10-22-30_13-07-2014.temp
```

notice the date_time.temp stamp part. The format here is **ABC_4digits_DEF_hours-minutes-seconds_day-month-year**

And I want to see only the new files created just now (say before 5 minutes from now). Approach using awk/sed is(pseudocode,let me know if u need me to copy actual one liner) :

1. `ls -lart|awk '{print $9}'|`
2. `egrep` to extract 10-22-30_13-07-2014
3. use sed to replace _ with -|awk to rearrange the to have the number in the format  YEARMONTHDAYHOURSMINUTESSECONDS.
4. use awk again to compare this number using if($1>$mynum) against the variable(which supposedly has a number in the same format representing TODAYS TIME - 5 minutes)

**Problem:**
But for some reason(other complexities) i thought of writing it in perl and i found that the if condition **if ($1>$mynum)** throws error when i am using it in perl using system command. It says syntax error for using '>' even when using with single quotes,double quotes,no quotes.

Can someone tell me in general:

1. Why would someone NOT use awk,sed instead of perl in this scenario if given a choice?
2. Generic explanation not specific to this problem on things one should remember while including awk or sed inside perl(which hopefully should solve this specific problem too.

Comment: Please do not parse ls.

Comment: This question lacks focus.. anyway, just because something *can* be done doesn't mean it's a good way to do it. awk/sed are generally better paired directly with a shell, even though perl *can* rather easily invoke them (which doesn't imply it's a good approach).

Comment: You could easily perform this type of task with with `ls | sort`. Sometimes a less complicated solution is not obvious or perhaps overlooked.

Comment: guys, maybe you were looking to solve a specific question. But what i need is a "GENERIC" answer . Hence i asked a general question with an example and asked for Generic answer only.

Comment: Thing is your example is pretty bad. You're using the wrong tools - if you want to find files created in the last five minutes, use `find` with `-mtime` (or another of the time switches). Your problem is a rather simple syntax issue. There's no generic "don't use foo in perl", just that perl can do whatever awk and sed can do. So just use the right tool.

Comment: @anurag86 There is no absolute "generic answer" which is why a "generic question" is quite terrible; however, using perl only as glue (i.e. callout to awk/sed/ls) is often, imoho, a sign of not using/understanding perl's facilities (standard functions/operators or available modules) as they apply to the task.

Comment: @anurag86 That is, instead of asking such an open question, ask a question about a *real* (singular) problem that is being solved; then let go of the notion of needing to use awk/sed at all. If you get a syntax error, then that's just an *incorrectly written [perl] program* and otherwise has no bearing on using perl vs awk/sed (in any form). The/a solution in this case is to learn perl and fix the coding error.

Comment: @user2864740 : ok so then why dont you tell me what to use instead of awk/sed in perl in this scenario(treat it as a specific question).

Comment: I don't see a focused question or problem description; only a plea for a "general answer".

Answer (score 6):

> Why would someone NOT use awk,sed instead of perl in this scenario if given a choice?

If you like the idea:

- to fork a shell from perl
- inside a shell
- fork again two processes (ls & awk) what will only print the 9th column

**feel free to do it**. It sounds a terrible idea for me, but you knows: *your mileage...*

> Generic explanation not specific to this problem on things one should remember while including awk or sed inside perl(which hopefully should solve this specific problem too :) )

Generic things to remember:

- escaping rules of `$variables` - like `$9` what can be interpreted:

  - by the perl itself (e.g. the `$9` can be an perl variable storing the regex captures)
  - by the forked shell (e.g. `$9` can be an `shell` variable holding the 9th positional arg)
  - by the `awk` (where it means the 9th column)
- to know how to handle system error codes
- and mainly - any programming task need to know at least the basics of the used programming language. (it is like my english - it is terrible, but enough good to write an answer) :)

To your example: The `ls -lart|awk '{print $9}` is one of the worst thing what you can do.

Imagine:

- if you have file with name: `this is my file.txt`
- What will print the `ls -lart|awk '{print $9}`?

Guessed right, will  print only the `this`. Of course, this is wrong. Parsing filenames what
comes from `stdin` is always terrible idea (unless you have NULL terminated filenames), because filenames can contain whitespaces - not only `spaces` but `tab` or `newline` characters too.

To your second example:

- instead of running 4 programs in chain (pipes) you can use `find` to achieve the wanted: `print only new files modified in the last 5 min`
- with perl you can use perl modules:

  - [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) - can do anything what the `find` command does and much more
  - [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) - Alternative interface to File::Find
  - and many other modules: [see](https://metacpan.org/search?q=File%3A%3AFind) from the `File::Find` family
  - but you can use e.g. the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) or `Class::Path` or similar modules
  - etc...

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem with the approach. One niptick: Parsing filenames from `stdin` is not always terrible, the classic example is `find ... -print0 | xargs -0l ....`. As long as the filenames are NULL terminated, then you can parse them safely from stdin.

Comment: @user000001 :) youre absolutely right! (`print0 | xargs -0` is one of my favoriets in bash) I only don't wanted add to much complications to my answer, it will rather confuses the OP more... ;)